# How to fit a model using cross validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I need help understanding and implementing K-Fold cross validation.

As far as I understand cross validation, it is used to divide the dataset into k subgroups, to have a greater variation in the training and test data.
So my first question is: does it replace an ordinary `train_test_split()`, or is it used as an addition, when I want to save and reuse the model?

When I create a model like this:

```
X = df["A"]
y = df["B"]

model = LinearRegression()

kfold = KFold(shuffle=True, n_splits=10)
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=kfold)
```

And I save it to reuse it on real data, I get the error that the model has no `predict`-method and has not been fitted yet. If I just call `model.fit(X, y)` in the end, the scores don‘t get considered, do they?

How do I correctly fit the model using cross validation, so I can save and use it afterwards?

Comment: K-Fold cross validation is not used to actually train a model, it is only used for evaluation.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy just for understanding, why is it then considered as a way to prevent overfitting, if it doesn’t actually influence the model?

Comment: It is not a way to prevent overfitting, this is a common misconception.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy so the answer provided below, which creates submodels and averages them into a final model is not the actual thought of it?

Comment: Yes, what is averaged is a performance metric, not a model.

Comment: Meaning, I can only get a more realistic picture about the real accuracy of my model and the whole process of training and validating submodels is only to come to that metric? So it might only help me detect overfitting by providing me better insight of the model?

Answer (score 1):

To your first question:
It is an alternative method. You can think of it as doing a train_test_split 10 times on the dataset with no overlap in the test data. What you get is a more valid score because you use the model on the whole dataset.

[image]

To your second question:
You just need to fit the model. You either define a training set (by train_test_split) and fit it on that and use cv for evaluation, use the whole training set, or the most sophisticated: you loop over your folds, and fit a seperate model for each training set. For the final prediction you average over your models.

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=10)
for fold,(train_ids, valid_ids) in enumerate(kf.split(
            df)): 
    Xtrain = df.loc[train_ids,'A']
    ytrain = df.loc[train_ids,'B']
    Xvalid = df.loc[valid_ids,'A']
    yvalid = df.loc[valid_ids,'B']
    model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
    model.score(Xvalid, yvalid)
    model.save_model(..)
```

Then for  choosing the final model, you can either use the best performing or as mentioned above use all 10 models and averaging the predictions.

Comment: This is not correct, the predictions are not averaged in K-Fold cross-validation.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I was not talking about cross validation, I meant if 10 models are fitted there are multiple ways to chose the final model. One is to ensemble these models.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It doesn't really make sense in that context. In your code, there are actually 10 individual models, and if you shuffle the models themselves will change. The cross_val_score is essentially for you to evaluate whether or not your features and model types work well for your problem.

You need a separate fit step in order to use it downstream.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to train/test your model first. Then utilize k fold to further validate your model based on splitting your sample set.

The two concepts are separate.